# Find the window of an element inside an iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, window

Is there a cross browser method of returning the window object of an element whether it be in an iframe.

This does the job for me but I don't know how well supported it is or if jQuery has a solution.

```
var edoc = elem.ownerDocument.defaultView || elem.document.parentWindow;
```

Comment: Which one do you want? Element's position or mouse position? Add the code you have now, please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work in all major browsers. To clarify it - the first part is for non-IE browsers while the second targets IE. To the best of my knowledge jQuery does not provide a shortcut for that code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `frame.contentWindow`

```
var win = iframeElement.contentWindow;
```

Comment: Sorry, the element is inside the iframe. Don't have a reference the iframe.